# What does the "=" do in ```export class NgForOfContext<T, U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>> {```

Tags: angular, typescript

I was looking at the source for ngForOf in Angular and I came across this line:

```
export class NgForOfContext<T, U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>> {
```

see: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L14

I played around with the = operator and changed it to & and |. However, even with the typescript docs I couldn't figure out what the = operator actually does.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't pass anything to `U`, then `U` will fall back to `NgIterable<T>` as a default value.

[See docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)

Comment: Thank you. I'll file that under "Things only documented in obscure change logs a few years back." Didn't even  know what to search for ...